# Es campo pero se utiliza como tipo

Tags: c#

Estoy intentando generar una list en C# pero cuando intento usae el metodo add arroja el error "Es campo pero se utiliza como tipo" no entiendo a que se refiere.¿ podrían ayudarme ? este es mi código

```
 List<Area> areas = new List<Area>();


 Area area1 = new Area("Acuario de Veracruz");
 Area area2 = new Area("Playa Mocambo");
 areas.add(area1);       

 Area area3 = new Area("Acuario Inbursa");
 Area area4 = new Area("Museo Soumaya");
```

Comment: En que linea te da el error?

Comment: ese código es el del problema o lo reescribiste aquí en el site? esto porque  el metodo 'add' no existe, ya que c# es case-sensitive. Por otro lado sin el numero de linea es complicado, ya que el error puede estar pasando en el constructor, ademas es un error de compilación o de ejecución?

Comment: a esta persona le da el mismo error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14154567/field-but-is-used-like-a-type

Comment: Añade la definición de `Area`, ya que el codigo que nos enseñas (obviando que el metodo `Add()` tiene la primera en mayusculas) es correcto.

Answer (score 2):

seguramente tengas definido

```
areas.add(area1);
```

A nivel de clase, fuera de un método. Sin mostrarnos el código de la clase poco más puedo aportar. Un saludo